# How to display the internationalization "second"/"seconds" string for a number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and, given a number, I would like to display the  internationalization "second"/"seconds" string for that number. That is, I have a number (for example, 1 or 20) and I would like to display `1 second` or `20 seconds` (in english).

I know the [date helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html) but no method seems to fit for my case. How can I make that?

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize

Comment: Your question is misleading. At first, it sounds like you want internationalization. Then by presenting `second`, `seconds`, it sounds like you just want English.

Comment: @sawa - I don't want just English but even support for all other languages. For example, is the following correct (note: I am using translation strings provided by Rails)? `number = 3; number == 1 ? t('datetime.distance_in_words.x_seconds.one') : t('datetime.distance_in_words.x_seconds.other', :count => number)`.

Comment: Doesn't `t` take care of the pluralization for you? It has to, it wouldn't make any sense at all for it not to. I use gettext but I'd assume the default `t` stuff has at least a modicum of sense.

Comment: @mu is too short - You are right: `t('datetime.distance_in_words.x_seconds', :count => number)`. Post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual `t` function eventually ends up inside the i18n gem's `translate` method. `translate`, like any sensible i18n/l10n tool, already knows about the current locale's pluralization rules. That means that you should just tell the translation system which message/string you want to how many of them you have, something like:

```
t('message-identifier', :count => n)
```

Then `t` will use the appropriate pluralization rules for `n` things in the current locale.

I use gettext for all my translation needs and it behaves this way. But there's no possible way that `t` wouldn't work this way too; it must work this way or it is utterly useless.